# Circular dependency on Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, countries

I'm having this error while running *bundle install*:

> Your Gemfile requires gems that depend on each other, creating an infinite loop. Please remove gem 'casein' and try again.

The error started when I added the gem **countries** to Gemfile.

I think it's a weird bug, because countries and casein have very different dependencies:

```
Puelos-Macbook:ChataBackend paulo$ gem dependency countries
Gem countries-0.11.4
  currencies (~> 0.4.2)
  i18n_data (~> 0.7.0)
  rspec (>= 3, development)
  yard (>= 0, development)

Puelos-Macbook:ChataBackend paulo$ gem dependency casein
Gem casein-5.0.0.0
  authlogic (= 3.4.2)
  casein (>= 0)
  jquery-rails (>= 0)
  scrypt (= 1.2.1)
  will_paginate (= 3.0.5)
```

edit:

Just to be sure, I removed all other gems from my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'countries'
gem 'casein', '5.0.0'
```

But the error persists

Comment: https://gist.github.com/puelocesar/220f087c543259146e28

*bundle update* gives me the same error

Comment: delete your `gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, sorry, I didn’t get this at the first glance.

`casein` gem references itself:

```
Puelos-Macbook:ChataBackend paulo$ gem dependency casein
Gem casein-5.0.0.0
  authlogic (= 3.4.2)
  !! NB⇒ casein (>= 0)
  jquery-rails (>= 0)
  scrypt (= 1.2.1)
  will_paginate (= 3.0.5)
```

It was allowed for bundle prior to `1.9`, but disallowed now. You have two options:

1. downgrade `bundler` to `1.8` and re-run `bundle install`.
2. clone the `casein` gem, patch `casein.gemspec` by removing self-reference and submit a pull-request. https://github.com/spoiledmilk/casein3/blob/master/casein.gemspec#L103

*NB* Actually this was already done by community, e.g. https://github.com/russellquinn/casein 
So, you might simply require that version explicitly via `gem 'casein', git: 'github.com:russellquinn/casein'`.

Hope it helps.